# Conditional Statements are not Executing?

Tags: python, function, if-statement, input, while-loop

I have written a Program that adds and multiples first ten Natural Numbers on user input. I have made two separate functions for Addition and Multiplication and called both functions in a while loop using if-else statement in it. But it is taking input from user but not performing any further operations. Code is Below:

```
print("Please select one of the Following Functions:")
print("1. Add First Ten Numbers")
print("2. Multiply first ten Numbers")
user=input()

plus=0
mul=1

for a2 in range(11):
    if a2>0:
        plus=plus + a2
        mul=mul * a2


def add():
    print("Sum of First Ten Numbers is",plus)

def product():
    print("Product of First Ten Numbers is",mul)

while True:
    if user == 1 and user !=2:
        add()
    elif user == 2:
        product()
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Try: “1” == 1 (hint: it’s not true; str == int is never true in Python).

Comment: `if user == 1 and user !=2:`  <-- this line of code. If user == 1, then for sure user != 2 (so the second part of that expression isn't needed).

Answer (score 1):

add int in user = input()
and put break in while loop

```
print("Please select one of the Following Functions:")
print("1. Add First Ten Numbers") 
print("2. Multiply first ten Numbers")
user=int(input())

plus=0
mul=1

for a2 in range(11):
  if a2>0:
    plus=plus + a2
    mul=mul * a2


def add():
    print("Sum of First Ten Numbers is",plus)

def product():
   print("Product of First Ten Numbers is",mul)

while True:
    if user == 1 and user !=2:
         add()
         break;
     elif user == 2:
        product()
        break;
```

Answer (score 0):

`user=input()` returns a string.

So that in your if-statement you should compare with a string literal `'1'`.

Alternatively write `user=int(input())` to cast `input()` value to `int`. But here exception can be thrown if you enter not valid int.